# Where is this Query parameter psafe_param coming from?

Tags: urlsearchparams

We are running a WP website and we see that on some linke a query parameter is added?
[https://example.com/?psafe_param=1glcid={some](https://example.com/?psafe_param=1glcid=%7Bsome) long hash string}

We have no clue where it is coming from?

We searched everywhere in WP for this but can not find the cause?

Can anyone explain this?

We disabled all the plugins and it still is there but not always.